# Is a SSH key required for SFTP?

Tags: sftp, ssh-host-key

Since SFTP stands for SSH + FTP, I assume I always should create a SSH key pair for it, however, I see in my client configuration that that is optional.

That is applicable for both server-side and client-side SSH key pair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A host key is mandatory for any ssh server. The server can have multiple host keys using different algorithms. If no key is present when the server is started a host key is generated for the server.

An ssh client can authenticate with a wide range of different methods. The two most common are `password` and `publickey`. As the name suggests only `publickey` requires a key. It is very often recommended to use `publickey` as it has multiple security benefits compared to `password`, and `publickey` is also better for the user experience.

The above applies both when using `ssh` to run commands on the remote machine as well as when using `scp` or `sftp` to transfer files. Once your keys have been created the same key files will be used for all three commands.